# How to create columns by combining two rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

Hi I have a df like this,

```
    0     1    2       3
0   A     B    NaN     C
1   D     NaN  E       F
2   one   two  three   four
3   five  six  sev     egght
```

I am trying to create a new column for my df by combining row1 and row2, I can do that by adding the rows and replacing it to the columns and removing the duplicated rows. but I am looking for a pandorable way of doing this.

My expected output is,

```
    A D     B    E     C F
0   one   two  three   four
1   five  six  sev     egght
```

replace `NaN with ''`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select first 2 rows by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and replace `NaN`s by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html).

Then join by space, but need remove trailing whitespaces by [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
cols = df.iloc[:2].fillna('')
df.columns = (cols.iloc[0] + ' ' + cols.iloc[1]).str.strip()

df = df.iloc[2:]
print (df)
    A D    B      E    C F
2   one  two  three   four
3  five  six    sev  egght
```

Or better join all non `NaN`s values with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df.columns = df.iloc[:2].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.dropna()))
df = df.iloc[2:]
print (df)
    A D    B      E    C F
2   one  two  three   four
3  five  six    sev  egght
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `str.cat`, `iloc` slicing and `rename`

```
In [1008]: df.iloc[2:].rename(columns=df.iloc[:2].apply(lambda x: x.str.cat(sep=' ')))
Out[1008]:
    A D    B      E    C F
2   one  two  three   four
3  five  six    sev  egght
```

---

Details

```
In [1012]: df.iloc[:2].apply(lambda x: x.str.cat(sep=' '))
Out[1012]:
0    A D
1      B
2      E
3    C F
dtype: object
```